# How can I have figure caption at bottom and yet create a reference to the top of the figure?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, labels

How can I draw a floating figure such that the following conditions are satisfied:

1. The figure caption appears below the figure.
2. When I add a `\ref` to the figure in another page, clicking the reference takes me to the top of the figure (not the bottom of the figure where the caption is).

Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Hello}
\subsection{Hello World}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw=black,minimum size=5cm]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Circle}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak

\subsection{Hello Human}
Figure \ref{fig} demonstrates a large circle.

\end{document}
```

I compile this code as follows:

```
pdflatex foo.tex && pdflatex foo.tex
```

The PDF generated violates condition 2. When I click on the figure reference in page 2, it jumps to the bottom of the figure in page 1 (not the top of it).

Answer (score 3):

The following two possibilities seem to work, at least for your MWE.

1: Include the package `caption` in your preamble

2: Include the package `hypcap` after loading hyperref as follows:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
```

Note: the second solution will not compile when you include additional `figures` without a `caption`.